# Re-format filesystem error starting Hadoop services on Mac

Tags: macos, hadoop, namenode

iMac 2020 Intel, MacOS Monterey 12.6, Java 1.8, Hadoop 3.3.4 as at 9-Feb-23

I am getting this error when starting Hadoop with this command:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh
```

Irrespective of response as Y or N, the error keeps running on the terminal and never stops.

> localhost: Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory root=
> /tmp/hadoop-arshadssss/dfs/name; location= null ? (Y or N) Invalid
> input:

[image: Hadoop start error]

I followed the steps from https://techblost.com/how-to-install-hadoop-on-mac-with-homebrew/ to install and configure. It feels like all is done and this is final step...any help/support to resolve would be appreciated.

I tried killing the namenode process from activity monitor and re-starting to no avail

Answer (score 0):

`start-all` is a deprecated script.

You should use `start-dfs` and `start-yarn` separately.

Or use `hdfs namenode start`, for example, and same for datanode, `yarn resourcemanager`, nodemanager, etc. all separately.

Then debug which daemon is actually causing the problem